# Image map in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, imagemap, flex-builder-3

Anyone have an example of doing something like an image map in Flex? I'm not sure if that is the correct term, since I also want to do things like highlight the selected part of the image or show a popup bubble pointing to it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: [flexlib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/wiki/ComponentList) > ImageMap