# How to manage Mouse clicks on Irregular Button shapes in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, button, shapes

In Flex, I am trying to design 3 buttons similar to the image uploaded at
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f14d58b49e.jpg

The mouse over/click on image should work only on red colored area of the button.
How can I manage the Mouse clicks or Irregular Button shapes in Flex?

Thnx ... Atul

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [flexlib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/wiki/ComponentList) > ImageMap.

Taken from [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535003/image-map-in-flex)

Answer (score 0):

Use button skins based on a vector graphic (e.g., one made in Illustrator), save each state as a named symbol in the document, then export as SWF. Reference the skins as follows:

```
.stepButton {
        upSkin: Embed(source="myfile.swf", symbol="StepButton"); 
        downSkin: Embed(source="myfile.swf", symbol="StepButtonDown");
        overSkin: Embed(source="myfile.swf", symbol="StepButtonOver");
        disabledSkin: Embed(source="myfile.swf", symbol="StepButtonDisabled");
}
```

Flash will automatically determine the hit area from the visible portion. This example (not called "myfile.swf") is working for us right now in an application.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create ArrowButtonsHolder class by inheriting from Canvas
2. Create 3 children classes also inherited from Canvas. For example LeftArrowButton, MiddleArrowButton, RightArrowButton

   public class LeftArrowButton:Canvas {
       protected override function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
       {
           super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

   ```
       // draw your arrow here
       // use graphics to do it 
       graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
       graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
       graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
       graphics.lineTo(30, 0);
       graphics.lineTo(50, 25);
       graphics.lineTo(30, 50);
       graphics.lineTo(0, 50);
       graphics.lineTo(0, 0);
       graphics.endFill();
   }
   ```

   }

   You also can create general class ArrowButton and inherit another 3 from that class and override drawing function
3. Add this 3 child button object to ArrowButtonsHolder by overriding createChildren():void method

   ```
   public class ArrowButtonsHolder:Canvas {

   // ...

   private var leftArrowButton:LeftArrowButton;
   private var middleArrowButton:MiddleArrowButton;
   private var rightArrowButton:RightArrowButton;

   // ...

   protected override function createChildren():void {
       super();

       // create buttons
       leftArrowButton = new LeftArrowButton();
       middleArrowButton = new LeftArrowButton();
       rightArrowButton = new LeftArrowButton();

       // add them to canvas
       addChild(leftArrowButton);
       addChild(middleArrowButton);
       addChild(rightArrowButton);

       // position these button by adjusting x, y
       leftArrowButton.x = 0; 
       middleArrowButton.x = 50; 
       rightArrowButton.x = 100; 

       // assign event listeners
       leftArrowButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onLeftArrowButtonClick);
       middleArrowButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMiddleArrowButtonClick);
       rightArrowButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onRightArrowButtonClick);
   }

   private onLeftArrowButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
   {
       trace("Left button clicked");
   }

   // .. etc for another 2 methods implemented here
   ```

   }

PS: There might be tons of syntax mistakes in my code but you should get general idea how to do it