# how to add click event on image area on flex?

Tags: apache-flex, image, events

Can i create img map and then add several click event?
for example this img-
I have 4 area for event top-left, top-right etc.
How i can do this?

[image]

I need something like tag map on HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to set the buttonMode to true on your image, add a click handler to it, then check if the point that got clicked is in any of the particular areas you care about.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [flexlib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/wiki/ComponentList).  I found this via a search and the result was already in StackOverflow: [Image map in Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535003/image-map-in-flex)  So technically this question is a duplicate.